# Netbeans 8.0.2 fail to run a simple hello world program

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, pom.xml

Showing an error of the sorts

```sh
Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.2.1: 
Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:pom:1.2.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
Failed to transfer file:
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:Not Implemented. -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Please show your `pom.xml` as it seems to be a maven problem. Please also share your used commands.

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 1):

This might be an issue with resolving the dependency. Can you try below and get back.

Open the .m2/repository and proceed to the path org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/. Then delete the subdirectory 1.2.1 and the entire content. Then the maven will automatically download the dependency in the next update. Try to build the project and see.

Additionally you can try to issue below command in command prompt at the project directory.(This command will update the dependencies forcefully)

mvn clean install -U